# Excel horizontal chart with color bars and a marker

Tags: microsoft-excel, diagrams

I need to create a diagram with sections (yellow to red) and a marker at a % position. This is just an example.

[image: example diagram]

Comment: Are Y looking for slider sort of object where with Mouse move /hover on each segment related Data percentage should appear or Data percentage should appear side by all color/ segment ?

Comment: Or you want to just draw thick line with marker on each segment ?

Comment: As far as I know, Excel can't create a single-line bar chart, you can only display each piece of data in a different row.

Comment: I would like to set a value into a cell and the graphic get's generated, so i can generate a report as PDF in the end. The viewer should just be able to see, in which area the value belongs to. (used for an adipose analysys report on a printout).

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this? Please edit your post with your research and details of your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

[Image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze4TO.jpg)I did the following and it works:

- Set all column width to 1.25
- Insert values 1 - 100 in A1-CV1 and change the font colour to white to hide them
- Create your scale by filling the cells colour in red, yellow and green in A2-CV2
- In C3 use the following code `=IF($E$6=A1,"▲","")` and drag this along to CV3.
- In Cell E6 put your value you want to show on the scale.

The triangle will go underneath the cell set.

Comment: Thanks! This is principally what i was searching for. It works, but it's complicated to insert this graphic from Excel into MS word.

Comment: Remove the gridlines and screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I convinced myself I didn't know how to do this. And maybe even that it probably couldn't be done in an easy way.

However...

[image]

This is a stacked bar chart. The data:

[image]

The "Green" series has two bars, but the one on top, which has a value that you change in cell A3, is set to no fill, no border, labels inside-end with the label formatted as a callout that points towards the gridline of the bar underneath it.

[image]

What I couldn't figure out a good way to do was the make the callout vertically on top of the gridline without it becoming out of place when you change the value.

Disclaimer: The whole thing falls apart if you change the shape of the chart. :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!